# Meaning of 'throw()' in destructor signature

Tags: c++, exception

The following is a custom exception class from another person's c++ tutorial:

```
class MyException : public std::exception {
public:
    MyException(const std::string message) : m_message(message) { }
    ~MyException() throw() { }
    const std::string what() const throw() { return m_message.c_str(); }

private:
    std::string m_message;
}
```

I get most of what going on here,, except for the "throw()" right next to the destructor..

Does it mean throw() is called whenever the exception class is destructed..??

Comment: throw() is not a method here

Comment: `throw()` indicates that the function will not throw an exception under any scenario. By the way, there's no point storing `message` in your class if you inherit from `std::exception`, because `std::exception` already keeps a `message` string. Just pass the message through in the constructor.

Comment: On a side note; the signature for `what()` does not match the signature in `std::exception`. You may want it to match `const char* what() const throw();` ref http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/exception/exception/

Answer (score 5):

This is an [exception specification](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/except_spec).

It means that the destructor is not supposed to throw any exception. If it attempts to throw one anyway, the program will invoke `std::terminate` (which will almost certainly crash the program). Note that not all compilers implement this behavior correctly (most notably, in VC++ throwing from a destructor declared `throw()` [leads to unspecified behavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wfa0edys.aspx)).

Note that exception specifications have been deprecated with C++11 in favor of [noexcept](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept) and should no longer be used (for [good reasons](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill22.htm)). Destructors are implicitly noexcept in C++11.

Comment: Note that many compilers (including VS) still do not implement `noexcept`.

Comment: @JamesKanze True. The November 2013 CTP has partial support for the unconditional `noexcept`, but that one does not come with a 'Go Live' license and is hence not fit for production use. Let's hope this gets fixed soon.

Comment: throw() seems to be deprecated in C++11 and already removed.

Answer (score 2):

It's a declaration of what the function is allowed to throw. In this case, nothing.

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/except_spec

If you don't list an exception type inside the `throw()` and you later try to throw one from that function, you'll get an `std::unexpected` thrown instead.

If the `throw()` is left out as it usually is, then any exception may be thrown.